# Drop down menu not showing with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am a beginner in Django, I tried making a drop down menu and select one option. I am not able to do it. Please could you help my out with it.

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from .models import website, PresetList

class PresetListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PresetList
        exclude=[]
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode      
from django import forms


class PresetList(models.Model):
    VIEWS = (
        ('1', 'X'),
        ('2', 'Y'),
    )
    query_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VIEWS)
    #code
```

views.py

```py
def my_view(request):
    preset_form = PresetListForm()
    return render_to_response('signup.html',{'preset_form': preset_form},RequestContext(request))
```

signup.html

```html
<html> 
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %} {{ preset_form.as_p }} </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you get some error or form is not just rendered?

Comment: not rendered... I am getting a totally blank page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I figured out what is wrong with your code.
You are using `forms.ChoiceField()` to define model field what is not correct.
You should use `models.CharField()` instead:

```
query_choice = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=VIEWS)
```

Comment: Thanks it has worked for me :) 
can you please just tell one more thing. If I need to populate the drop-down menu with the enteries from database, so which query to run in that case:)...

Comment: In that case you need to create separate model with needed values and link with existing model as `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Or you can use ModelChoiceField and then inside the form's init function call the query, like:

self.fields['query_choice'].queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()